# Start-BitsTransfer failing to send files to remote destination

Tags: powershell

I am using the following command to send local files to a remote location that is mapped on my F drive:

```
Start-BitsTransfer -Source C:\Source\*.* -Destination F:\Destination -Description "Backing up files to remote destination" -DisplayName "Full Backup $((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd'))" -TransferType Download
```

My upload is failing when the progress is about 70%.

This is the error I am getting:

```
Start-BitsTransfer : Invalid Signature.
At C:\backup\MyBackUp.ps1:65 char:2
+     Start-BitsTransfer -Source C:\Source\*.* -Destination F:\Destination\ -Des ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-BitsTransfer], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StartBitsTransferCOMException,Microsoft.BackgroundIntelligentTransfer.Management.NewBitsTransferCommand
```

Any suggestion or recommendation?

Thank you.

Comment: Comment: `TransferType` is not required when both Source and Destination are specified. Question: what error message or code is returned when failing?

Comment: @harrymc I just added the error on the question. Thank you.

Comment: Probably should set /SetSecurityFlags

Comment: @Ramhound How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The
[Start-BitsTransfer command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/bitstransfer/start-bitstransfer?view=windowsserver2019-ps)
may not be the best choice here, as its documentation says:

> The Start-BitsTransfer cmdlet supports the download of multiple files from a server to a client computer, **but it does not generally support the upload of multiple files from a client computer to a server**. If you need to upload more than one file, you can use the Import-Csv cmdlet to pipe the output to the Add-BitsFile cmdlet to upload multiple files. Or, if you need to upload more than one file, consider a cabinet file (.cab) or a compressed file (.zip).

The documentation also says the following (which I suspect is wrong):

> When you upload files to an HTTP location, the *TransferType* parameter must be set to *Upload*.

The error message "Invalid Signature" might be returned because the
credential used by the server is not accepted, for example if it's
self-signed.

Your might be able to use the `-SecurityFlags` parameter to disable
the error, but the parameters are not explained at all in the
documentation. The following might be helpful:
*IgnoreCertCNInvalid, IgnoreCertDateInvalid, IgnoreUnknownCA,
IgnoreCertWrongUsage*.

As an alternative, you could use instead the
[WebClient.UploadFile Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.uploadfile?view=net-6.0),
which does not check certificates.

Comment: How can I use this -SecurityFlags ?
I also tried IgnoreCertCNInvalid, IgnoreCertDateInvalid, IgnoreUnknownCA, IgnoreCertWrongUsage, but couldn't use them, it seems they are unavailable when tabbing for command completion.

Comment: I haven't found any documentation or examples of using these flags, and I have really tried. It seems like nobody ever used them.